# In an MVC Data List what is the best way to toggle conditions in a SQL Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, .net-core

Please excuse me, I am new to MVC and Entity Framework but have been unable find information to solve my problem.

Problem 1 is that I am trying add a where statement to my model and show only active players. You can see my two separate procedures in my controller, but they both yield the same results.

```
   public IActionResult ActivePlayers()
   {
        var model = _playerRepository.GetAllPlayers();
        return View("Players",model.Where(d => d.IsActive = true));
   }
   public IActionResult AllPlayers()
   {
        var model = _playerRepository.GetAllPlayers();            
        return View("Players", model);
   }
```

My second problem is I am having a hard time figuring how to toggle between All Players and Active ones from the View.
I tried the following, but quickly realized that it wouldn't work since the page is re-rendered after calling the controller. - Note, I was using jQuery to toggle viability.

```
<div>
    <label id="lblShowAll" style="color:green;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;"
           >Showing Active Players</label>
    <label id="lblLimitList" style="color:green;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;display:none;"
           >Showing All Players</label>
    <br />
    <a id="ShowAll" class="btn btn-link"
       asp-controller="admin" asp-action="allPlayers">Show All Players</a>
    <a id="LimitList" class="btn btn-link" style="display:none;"
       asp-controller="admin" asp-action="activePlayers">Limit List (Active Players)</a>
</div>
```

I'm not sure it matters but this is what my data list looks like in the View.

```
<div class="container" id="players">
    <br />
    <div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
        <table id="playerList" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap"
               width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th>Telephone</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var player in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <th>@player.Name</th>
                        <th>@player.Address</th>
                        <th>@player.City</th>
                        <th>@player.State</th>
                        <th>@player.Telephone</th>
                        <th>
                            <a class="btn btn-outline-info m-1"
                                asp-controller="admin" asp-action="editPlayer" asp-route-id="@player.PlayerId">
                               Edit</a>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <a class="btn btn-outline-danger m-1">Delete</a>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the ActivePlayers method you need to use a == when doing the comparison. Are you sure you have inactive players in your player respository?

Comment: Let's split it into 2 issue. First, do you have any InActive players so you can see different list (You still need to change your "Where(d => d.IsActive)". Second, if you want to toggle between full list and active list, you can load all, and use JavaScript to show/hide in-active users.

Comment: Worked like a charm - thank you both.. Definitely overlooked to obvious.